# Issue with dependencies & function being recognized in the repl

Tags: clojure

I am having a similar issue to this person: [Problems while creating a deps.edn file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65543714/problems-while-creating-a-deps-edn-file)

However, I'm on MacOS and trying to follow the book and use deps.edn instead of leiningen, so I wasn't able to solve my issue from reading the answers in that post.

I'm using my terminal window and just text files, or Emacs.

Within the terminal, I created a folder called tennisProject. Then I created 2 files, deps.edn and tennisProject.clj inside that folder. Then I put the csv file of tennis data in that folder.

Then I go back to the terminal and restart it. I make tennisProject the current directory. I type in "clj" to start a repl. Then I do (in-ns 'packt-clj.tennisProject) to get into the right namespace. Then, I type (first-match "match_scores_1991-2016_unindexed_csv.csv"), and I get an error:

Syntax error compiling at (REPL:1:1).
Unable to resolve symbol: first-match in this context

The contents are as follows (I copied and pasted from the book).

deps.edn:

```
{:deps
 {org.clojure/data.csv {:mvn/version "1.0.0"}
  semantic-csv/semantic-csv {:mvn/version "0.2.1-alpha1"}}}
```

tennisProject.clj:

```
(ns packt-clj.tennisProject
  (:require
   [clojure.data.csv :as csv]
   [clojure.java.io :as io]
   [semantic-csv.core :as sc]))


(defn first-match [csv]
  (with-open [r (io/reader csv)]
    (->> (csv/read-csv r)
         sc/mappify
     first)))
```

I have a few things different than the book: I changed the name from tennis to tennisProject because I kept making new folders after getting errors. I also changed the data.csv version from "0.1.4" to "1.0.0" because that's what was in the answer I linked, but that didn't resolve my issue. Then I also have semantic-csv/semantic-csv but in the book it's just semantic-csv. I changed that because the repl advised me to make the change.

If I just require the dependencies one by one in the repl, and define the function in the repl, everything works fine, but I really want to understand how all these files work together and I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the Clojure CLI / `deps.edn` assumes your source code is going to be in a tree under a folder called `src`.

The namespace in a Clojure file must "match" its filepath relative to `src` so for `packt-clj.tennisProject`, the file should be `src/packt_clj/tennisProject.clj` -- note the `-` in a namespace corresponds to an `_` in the filepath.

If you reorganize your project like that, and restart your REPL, you should be able to `require` your code and work with it.

As a stylistic note, we don't use camelCase much in Clojure: it would be more idiomatic to have `tennis-project` as the namespace (which means `tennis_project.clj` as the filename).

(edited to add this example session)

```
(! 556)-> pwd
/Users/sean/clojure/tennisProject
(! 557)-> ls
deps.edn    example.csv src
(! 558)-> tree
.
|____deps.edn
|____example.csv
|____src
| |____packt_clj
| | |____tennisProject.clj
(! 559)-> clj
Clojure 1.10.3
user=> (require 'packt-clj.tennisProject)
nil
user=> (in-ns 'packt-clj.tennisProject)
#object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x128c502c "packt-clj.tennisProject"]
packt-clj.tennisProject=> (first-match "example.csv")
{:some "42", :headers "A value", :in "1", :this "2", :file "3.333"}
packt-clj.tennisProject=> ^D
(! 560)-> cat src/packt_clj/tennisProject.clj 
(ns packt-clj.tennisProject
  (:require
   [clojure.data.csv :as csv]
   [clojure.java.io :as io]
   [semantic-csv.core :as sc]))


(defn first-match [csv]
  (with-open [r (io/reader csv)]
    (->> (csv/read-csv r)
         sc/mappify
     first)))
(! 561)-> cat example.csv 
some,headers,in,this,file
42,"A value",1,2,3.333
```

Comment: Hi Sean. Thanks for your help. I added the following folders. So I have tennisProject > src > packt_clj. Then I moved the other files so they are all within the packt_clj folder: The deps.edn, the tennisProject.clj, and the csv file. Then I went back to the terminal, changed my directory to be the packt_clj folder, typed clj, then (in-ns 'packt-clj.tennisProject), then tried (first-match "match_scores_1991-2016_unindexed_csv.csv") and got the same error again, that it cannot resolve the symbol. I appreciate any further advice. Thanks for letting me know about the styling also!

Comment: Is it always the case that you would use "-" to attach words, and only "_" for filenames? Is that because of the JVM?

Comment: Run clj in the tennisProject folder: Clojure expects to find the src folder in the directory where you run it, from there it will look down the tree to "match" the namespace you require (do not use in-ns until you have successfully require'd your code). I'll update my answer with more of an example of this to make it clearer.

Comment: Example session added. You'll probably find learning easier if you have an interactive way to ask questions and get answers: I recommend joining the Clojurians Slack and asking questions in the #beginners channel -- sign up at http://clojurians.net

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH SEAN!!! It worked and now I feel like I understand better how things in the filetree must be organized. I've never used slack before but I'll look into that for sure!